# SQLSTATE[22021] Encoding "UTF8"

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, encoding, utf-8

I'm using Laravel 5 and PostgreSQL for my project and I have an error with UT8 encoding.

> Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22021]: Character
>   not in repertoire: 7 ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding
>   "UTF8": 0xd6 0x57 (SQL: update "sessions" set "payload" = (...)
>   "user_agent" = Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; **Ö**WN S1 Build/LRX21M)
>   (...)

I think the **Ö** is the problem.

**database.php :**

```
'pgsql' => [
     ...
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
     ...
],
```

I just configured the laravel session with database insted of file. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session

How can I fix this in production ?
If I change the charset in Laravel do I need to change something in PostgreSQL ?

PostgreSQL config :

[image]

Thank's.

Comment: What charset and collation does your database have?

Comment: I just used this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session

Comment: @FabFuerste I set UTF8 in the config file.

Comment: That data is Latin-1 encoded. You'll have to be more clear about where it comes from.

Comment: I just configured the laravel session with database insted of file.

Comment: PostgreSQL config : https://puu.sh/xx6wn/e3cafb09c2.png

Comment: I see now, the problem is a user agent string containing non-UTF-8 data? That means some browser is sending Latin-1 encoded HTTP headers…? That's… tough. You should focus your question on that: how to deal with non-UTF-8 encodings in Laravel's session component, or something thereabouts.